# Connection between kernel estimator of derivative and derivative of kernel estimator

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

Imagine $X$ has density $f$ and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a given sample;

Now to estimate $f$ we can use

$$\hat f(x)=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{k=1}^nk\left(\frac{X_i-x}{h}\right),$$

for some differentiable kernel $k$ and this will converge to the true value if $h(n)\to 0$ and $n \to \infty$ (given some mild codition);

Now imagine we have a second random variable with density $g$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ be a given sample; Also, imagine that $g'(x)=f(x)$ in some interval $[a,b]$

Then for $x \in [a,b]$ it holds that $g'(x)=f(x)$ and therefore,

$$\hat g'(x)=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{k=1}^nk'\left(\frac{Y_i-x}{h}\right)\to \frac{1}{nh}\sum_{k=1}^nk\left(\frac{X_i-x}{h}\right),$$

however, I can't quite see why $\hat g'(x)$ converges to $\hat f(x)$. Can someone help?

---

So to assume an example: $k(x)=\frac{35}{32}(1-x^2)^31(\vert x\vert \leq 1)$, $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ is non-zero and in in the interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$ it holds that $g'(x)=f(x)$

Moreover let $h=1/log(n)$. Then, for $n \to \infty$ I want to prove that

$$\hat g'(x)=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{k=1}^nk'\left(\frac{Y_i-x}{h}\right)\to \frac{1}{nh}\sum_{k=1}^nk\left(\frac{X_i-x}{h}\right),$$

where $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ is an iid sample drawn from the density $g$ and $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ is an iid sample drawn from the density $f$ and $a<x<b$.

Comment: The result cannot possibly hold unless you make some additional assumptions about $k.$ For instance, it had better be differentiable!  Even if it is, I cannot see any basis for the step following your "therefore:" why should the derivative of an estimator of a density -- *any* estimator -- be anywhere close to the derivative of the density?

Comment: @whuber  Well assuming that $\hat g(x)$ is an (asymptotically) consistent estimator of $g(x)$ and assuming the kernel to be differentiable, it holds that $\hat g'(x)$ must also converge to $g'(x)$ and therefore to $f(x)$ (since g'(x) is differentiable and $g'(x)=f(x)$); And since $\hat f(x)$ is also a consistent estimator for $f(x)$, it should follow that $\hat g'(x) \to \hat f(x)$ if I am not mistaken??

Comment: "It holds that" is unjustified.  Indeed, there is no reason in general even for $\hat g$ to be differentiable. For instance, $k$ may have no derivative anywhere but nevertheless $\hat g$ can be asymptotically consistent.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your answer.. :-) But $\hat g$ is differentiable if and only if the kernel is differentiable so assuming that $k$ is differentiable, then the result should follow??

Comment: I think you will need additional technical assumptions, such as $k$ is differentiable with bounded derivative. It looks like you need some basic assumptions, too, such as that $g^\prime$ is everywhere nonzero.  Also, your equations don't make much sense: how are the samples $X_i$ and $Y_i$ related, for instance, and how is this convergence supposed to occur -- what is being varied, exactly?

Comment: Would it be possible in that specific example from above?

Comment: Your example isn't a kernel, because "$1(|x|\le x)$" evaluates to $1$ for non-negative $x$ and to $0$ otherwise. Note that assuming $f$ is a density definitely does not imply it is never zero! For instance, the density of the uniform distribution on $[a,b]$ is zero everywhere except on this interval.

Comment: @whuber I am so sorry, I had a typo - would my statement be true now? (assuming f and g are non-zero)?

Comment: Please notice that this $k$ is not everywhere differentiable. That problem can be overcome with a delicate treatment of the sums (they could be replaced by upper and lower bounds based on the subdifferential of $k$), but it highlights the fundamental difficulty associated with trying to estimate derivatives in the first place. Notice too that there do not exist any densities $f$ that are everywhere differentiable, nonzero, and have strictly positive derivatives that themselves are densities. Thus, your question becomes vacuous because it asks about things that don't exist.

Comment: @whuber shouldn't it be enough if $f'(x)=g(x)$ in some interval $[a,b]$? We can also take a kernel that is differentiable everywhere, e.g. $k(x)=35/32(1-x^2)^31(\vert x \vert \leq 1)$

Comment: That doesn't look like it's enough: the problem generally is that $k^\prime$ doesn't necessarily enjoy all the properties needed to demonstrate any kind of convergence.  For instance, it may oscillate infinitely often between the values $\pm 1$ even over a compact domain.

Comment: But that is clearly not the case for the kernel that I have chosen, right? So then it should be possible?

Comment: Which kernel? You have one in the question and one in your comments.  Also, shall we presume $h=1/\log(n),$ since $1/\log(x)$ doesn't work?

Comment: The latter kernel and $h=1/log(n)$, $1/log(x)$ was another typo... I am just curious of how we could possibly prove it given that we really have the conditions that we need